# C# Spawn new thread to access a web service to abort

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm putting together a simple C# app where a user types commands into a "command bar" and the results are fetched in real time.

For example I could type, `google stackoverflow`, and it sends an API call off to google, fetches each of the results and displays them in the ui.

Currently I fire off the "search" method if a user pauses for more than 1/4 of a second on typing, so if you paused in the middle it could fire `google stack` and `google stackoverflow`.

Now in reality the api is doing a (rather slow) database query and this causes the ui to lock up while the first search completes, before it tries to start on the second search.

Is there a simple (C# 4.0) way to run the search call in a separate thread that I can then cancel/abort if the user continues typing?

e.g.

```
Task<string> thread;

string getSearchResults(string input) {
    ... Do some work ...
}

string userPaused(string search) {
  if(this.thread.isRunning()) this.thread.Kill();

  this.thread = new Task<String>(getSearchResults(string input);

  return this.thread.result();
}
```

I've looked at the Tasks api and it doesn't look as if you can kill a task in the middle of work, it suggests using a while look and passing a `shouldStop` boolean, however during an API call to download the results there is no while loop.

The Threading documentation however points you to tasks if you need to get the return value.

Comment: Take a look at CancellationToken structure: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken.aspx. Seems like it's that you're looking for.

Comment: Tasks are probably what you are looking for. And you can cancel them: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396.aspx you need to use cancellation token to do that, and of course take care of cancelation inside your task's method. But since most of the job is DB query - you might just want to drop the task and don't care about the result at all (just take care of all exceptions) and fire new Task when search terms changes. Depends on what you need

Comment: Have you looked here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396.aspx

Comment: Based on your update, why not just create a simple thread and call abort on it?

Comment: I have looked at Tasks documentation using CancellationToken and don't have a way (like a while loop) to check if the thread should cancel. I just need it to give in.

Comment: @Marco, can you get a return value from a simple thread?

Comment: @Marco - Aborting thread is never a good idea. Creating thread for such small task is also not a good idea - that's why Tasks were created - for better performance and managability.

Comment: @PezCuckow - if you query database synchronously then there is nothing you can realy cancel. What you can do is to check if task was cancelled before returning value and then proceeding accordingly, like MSDN in links above avises. Also - you cannot get return value from thread, but you can use shared variable to do this - but you may need to do locking. But why bother, when tasks are so nice

Comment: [How to abort a list of tasks from the outside](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16375645/how-to-abort-a-list-of-tasks-from-the-outside)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you may do with `Tasks` is to create them, and then cancel when not needed any more. If you can't cancel operation you are doing (like database query) - you can always cancel before results get returned. Your code may be something like this (not tested, just a draft):

```
    var tokenSource2 = new CancellationTokenSource();
    CancellationToken ct = tokenSource2.Token;

    var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        var result = Database.GetResult(); // whatever database query method you use.
        ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        return result;
    }, tokenSource2.Token);
```

So as you can see it will query database and return value when no cancellation requested, but if you will try to cancell the task - it will not return value but rather throw `OperationCanceledException` you need to catch. For details visit [MSDN Task Cancellation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396.aspx), but I think this should give you an idea. Don't worry about big task number - if your query is not very slow it won't matter - user will not be able to trigger so many searches. If you have asynchronous way of querying database - you can improve this code a bit more, but that also shouldn't be too hard.